# Domain name expired and sold to New Venture Services

Tags: domains

My domain name expired and although I was working with my Network Solutions to update my information somehow they let my name go and it was picked up by NVS Corp. At this point I can not get any information from anyone as to how I can purchase it back. My question is I spent thousands of dollars on the actual web site...so where is the web site now?

Comment: As a webhost some years ago, I used NetSol because they were the only game in town. My office was only two blocks away and I knew some people very high up who could fix problems like this. Heck we went to lunch and dinner all the time and they tried very hard to recruit me to their team. But then the NetSol management changed and I found NetSol very difficult to work with. I switched immediately when the opportunity arose to GoDaddy when they were brand spanking new and I have not had any troubles since. Something you may want to think about.

Answer (score 2):

You only lost your domain name, not your website. Your website is right where you left it. You just can't see it right now because your domain name doesn't resolve to it anymore.

I don't know for sure but I suspect NVS Corp is one of those companies that buys expired domains solely for the purpose of monetizing their existing traffic. My guess is you will not be able to buy your domain back from them. But that's just speculation.

What you need to do is purchase a new domain, make sure you don't have any outdated or incorrect information when you register it, and point that to your website. Within an hour or so your website will be visible again.

This is going to kill your SEO as  all of the incoming links to your website will be outdated. You will need to contact the sites where you have links and ask them to update their links to your website with your new domain name.

Comment: This is certainly the best if you want the site up and running quick. Plus, trying to get the domain name back (like Digital Chris suggests) can cost you a lot of money. Unless you had an incredible domain name, it probably not going to be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to simply give up your domain name!  There are dispute resolution avenues available to you.  Usually, you want to contact the registrar you were using and discuss disputing this transfer.

From https://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/transfers/name-holder-faqs:

> **My domain name was transferred without my authorization. What do I do?**
>
> If you believe that your domain name was transferred to a new
>   registrar without your authorization or consent, please contact the
>   original registrar. Disputes between registrars over alleged
>   violations of the Inter-Registrar Transfer Policy may be initiated by
>   any ICANN-accredited registrar.
>
> **How do I find out why my transfer request was denied?**
>
> If your current registrar denies a transfer request, they are required
>   to provide you with the reason. Contact the registrar for assistance.
>   See above for the circumstances in which a registrar may legitimately
>   deny a transfer request.
>
> **My domain has been transferred to some other registrar without my
>   knowledge, and now it shows someone else as the owner. What do I do?**
>
> A registrar may only initiate a transfer if it has obtained a
>   completed Form of Authorization (FOA) from either 1) the registrant or
>   2) the administrative contact for the domain. The registrar must be
>   able to produce a copy of this documentation when it is requested.
>   Failure to do so is grounds for reversal of a transfer in the event
>   that a complaint is filed under the Transfer Dispute Resolution
>   Policy.
>
> Thus, the first step should be for your previous registrar to request
>   from the new registrar a copy of the form used for authorizing the
>   transfer. The registrar can then proceed with initiating a dispute as
>   appropriate. Contact your previous registrar for assistance.